# Introductory DSP Texts

Tags: fft, discrete-signals

I have an interview for a communication theory position and part of the interview requires basic knowledge of signal processing.

What are good introductory texts that cover the basics of signal processing?

Topics that should be covered, e.g., are:

- duality principles
- Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem
- oversampling

Comment: Honestly, if you've got an interview on a position that requires basics in a field that you don't have: an honest self-assessment whether that position would fit you well might be more in order than to learn the basics of a field that you can study for years through a white paper. If your interviewer isn't really bad at their job, they'll find out and potentially call out your superficial knowledge anyway.

Comment: @mmmm I didnt ask you whether you think I am suitable or not and I don't have to explain to you anything.  I asked simple question tutorial. If you dont know of any then maybe scroll past it. But I think you are just complicated person.

Comment: @George It's well-meaning. Alternatively, we need not know your intent - the impression is, "job hard, give cheats". I'd reformulate as "SP trivia" or try other outlets.

Comment: The "easiest" reference to read is Wikipedia. Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I got the job btw and its at Amazon :)

Comment: @mmmm I got the job :)